# Is there a way how to customize my keyboard layout in Xubuntu in a graphical way (by clicking)?

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, gui, keyboard-layout

Possible duplicate, but I really couldn't find a solution. I would like to adjust my US keyboard layout, e.g. to add possibility to type some special characters on combination of right Alt + another character, etc.

Moreover, my arrow up is dead, so until I buy another keyboard, I'd like to use my right shift as my arrow up, ASAP.

However, there seems to be no way how to edit my keyboard layout **easily** in Xubuntu :( I found no editor and I really don't want to spend years in some configuration files and terminal (not that I can't, but I really **really** don't want).

- [KLE](http://simos.info/blog/archives/747) - the only editor I could find, but no installation guide, no package, no PPA, no idea how to make it working (and uninstallable if not needed one day)
- [Editor in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/12027/34304) - apparently not present in Xubuntu
- I found [several](https://askubuntu.com/a/92801/34304) [tutorials](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1654199&highlight=.Xmodmap) how to change the layout, but they all seems to be complicated and not easy to follow. I don't want to spend a weekend in terminal or so, I am looking for an app to launch, make some clicking, finish my work by hitting Save button and - done!

Please, is there such solution? For humans?

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem? have the exact same.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But I am not looking for it any more, so there could exist something I am not aware of. Feel free to investigate and eventually answer this question.

Comment: I will drop Xubuntu desktop and only use it as a headless server with vagrant.

Comment: Look up `setxkbmap` or `localectl` and manual pages to do those changes you would llike to do .

Answer (score 0):

Try installing xfce4-xkb-plugin, just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type in the terminal:

```bash
sudo apt-get install xfce4-xkb-plugin
```

You can find it after the instalation in the desktop bar.

Comment: `xfce4-xkb-plugin` is the thing I can use for switching layouts on my panel, isn't it? But I wanted something to customize existing layouts or to create a new, custom one. I can't find any way how to do this with `xfce4-xkb-plugin`.

(Apart from that, it's buggy thing I hate, it can't even properly switch layouts and remember settings.)