# Ubuntu not respecting custom keymap

Tags: xorg, kubuntu, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have modified my keymap for `dvorak` in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`, but it does not load properly, even after multiple reboots. Suggestions?

**EDIT:** A partial solution I have found is overwrite a language that I haven't ever used. This leads me to believe that Ubuntu puts a temporary us map file somewhere that it pulls from, as I didn't even have to restart X to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

See answer of Zaz at https://askubuntu.com/a/12301/82618

Essentially, you need to append the variant list in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`. Doing so worked for me at least on Kubuntu 13.04 but is likely to work on Ubuntu, too.